# Batch File Set Variable From Contents of Text File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Please Please Please

can anyone explain why the following code works if I manually enter it line by line but it doesn't work if I try to execute it through a batch file?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

Set Source=%computername%
Set Backups=%Source%\c$\users\travel\desktop
Set Target=dan-2813-pc
Set Action=Restore

    IF EXIST "\\%Backups%\%Source%-OrgUnit.txt" (

      SET /p OrgUnit=<\\%Backups%\%Source%-OrgUnit.txt

      SET /p MoveOU=At the end of the %Action%, do you want to move %Target% to %OrgUnit% [Y/N]?

        )

ENDLOCAL
```

I'm at a complete loss for what I'm missing here.

Comment: Which part isn't working? You haven't actually described your problem at all. "It doesn't work" is a meaningless phrase.

Comment: DOH!  Sorry about that.

The %OrgUnit% variable isn't being set when the script is run from a batch file.  When I manually type it, it is.

The last line of the script should display something like:

At the end of the Restore, do you want to move dan-2813-pc to "CN=DAN-2810-PC,CN=Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=com"

Instead, what I'm getting is:  At the end of the Restore, do you want to move dan-2813-pc to

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Thanks Stephan but you can set that EnableDelayedExpansion is turned on (line 2).

Comment: When you run the batch file that "it doesn't work," are you using `CALL abatchfile.bat`?

Comment: Whether I 'CALL' it (i.e. C:>call script.bat) or not, the result is still the same.

Comment: enabling it is not enough. You also have to *use* it. See Anon Coward's answer.

Comment: Please do not place the problem description in a comment, edit your question instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help for `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` says:

```
ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION / DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    enable or disable delayed environment variable
    expansion. These arguments takes precedence over the CMD
    /V:ON or /V:OFF switches. See CMD /? for details.
```

And the help for `/V:` says:

```
/V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
        delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
        variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
        at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
        loop.
```

In other words, if you want to see the changed value of a enviornment variable after setting it within a block, you need to change your code to use `!` instead of `%`:

```
SET /p MoveOU=At the end of the %Action%, do you want to move %Target% to !OrgUnit! [Y/N]?
```

Comment: GOT IT!  Thank you so much!  I mistakenly thought the % and ! were interchangeable and not delimiters for variable expansion.